# How to add shapes based on strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, image, shapes

I am attempting to make my own version of a QR Code, however less complex with what can be put in as data. I have the code set up to where anyone can plug in up to 8 ASCII characters and the code would convert that into a string of the bit values for each character. What I am having trouble doing is placing black squares in the parts of the QR Code where they are required, and white ones where the black ones don't belong.

This is the blank QR Code Template I am using:

[image: Blank QR Code]

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
def show(img,wait=0,destroy=True):
    img=np.uint8(img)
    cv2.imshow("image",img)
    cv2.waitKey(wait)
    if destroy:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def data2bits(data):
    bits=""
    for i in range(len(data)):
        binary=str(bin(ord(data[i])))
        binary=binary.replace("0b","0")
        binary=binary.zfill(8)
        bits+=binary

    bits=bits.ljust(64,'0')
    print("\nThese are the bits of the data you put in:\n"+str(bits)+"\n")
    return bits
    
def bits2pixels(bits,qrCode):
    for i in range(150,412):
        for j in range(150,412):
            for k in range(0,len(bits)):
                if (bits[k]=="1"):
                    cv2.rectangle(qrCode,(i,j),(i+38,j+38),(0,0,0),-1)
                elif (bits[k]=="0"):
                    cv2.rectangle(qrCode,(i,j),(i+3,j+3),(255,255,255),-1)
    show(qrCode)


qrCode=cv2.imread("scan.png",0)
data=input("Put in the data you want and you will get the binary output for the first 8 characters.\nIf the data put in is less than 8 characters long, the bits will be filled up\nbut will be removed when the data is recompiled.\nType in your data: ")
data=data[:8]
bits=data2bits(data)
bits2pixels(bits,qrCode)
```

Currently, the code can take in data, convert it to bits, and it's supposed to place squares where they are needed. For example, if I have the following bits, "10010101", I want to convert them into the following sequence of black/white shapes, "BWWBWBWB". But if I run the code as it is currently, If the last bit is a 1, the whole section I have designated for scannable data turns black, and the opposite is true if the last bit is 0.

What should I change with my code so there is an 8 by 8 section for data? All help is appreciated.

Comment: The inner loop `for k in range(0,len(bits)):` iterates all of `bits` and on the last iteration effectively assigns only the last bit to a *cell*; then your other loops *move-to* another *cell* and do the same thing. Your outer loops only increment by one yet you are *painting* `38x3` cells so you are going to have overlap.

Comment: A text description of how the shapes are supposed to be placed on the image would be a nice addition to your question. Spacing between shapes? Placed top-to-bottom left-to-right? Things like that. An expected result?  Your image `qrCode` has a shape of `(600,600)` but you are assigning a three-tuple as if it is 3d - that is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I run the code as it is currently, If the last bit is a 1, the whole section I have designated for scannable data turns black, and the opposite is true if the last bit is 0.

The inner loop - `for k in range(0,len(bits)):` iterates all of bits and on the last iteration and effectively assigns only the last bit to a cell; then your other loops move-to another cell and do the same thing.

I've refactored by iterating over the bits and advancing the pixel location with each iteration. Your outer loops in `bits2pixels` increment by one so I will keep that.

```
def bits2pixels(bits,qrCode):
    i,j = 150,150
    step = 1
    for bit in bits:
        if (bit=="1"):
            dim = 38
            color = (0,0,0)
        elif (bit=="0"):
            dim = 3
            color = (1,1,1)
        cv2.rectangle(qrCode,(i,j),(i+dim,j+dim),color,-1)
        i += step
        j += step
    show(qrCode)
```

I'm not sure I captured your intent - the shapes end up on a diagonal. They all run together because the shapes are larger than the step.

---

Maybe this is closer. 40x40 locations for a *shape*; shapes placed left-to-right top-to-bottom.

```
def bits2pixels(bits,qrCode):
    i,j = 150,150
    step = 40
    for bit in bits:
        if (bit=="1"):
            dim = 38
            color = (0,0,0)
        elif (bit=="0"):
            dim = 3
            color = (1,1,1)
        cv2.rectangle(qrCode,(i,j),(i+dim,j+dim),color,-1)
        i += step
        if i >= 412:
            i = 150
            j += step
            if j >= 412:
                break
        # j += step
    show(qrCode)
```